# Error During Execution File Reading Code in VC++.net

Tags: c++, .net, visual-c++, compiler-errors

i am trying to read text file containing near about  60000 words.
Here is Code i have written for it..Compiler shows this error message: 
**Unhandled exception at 0x77cee3be in FileReading.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x02affa79.** for this line 
cout<<"Reading Words...<
But when i ran this code in debug mode.. compiler didnt shows any error. every thing works fine.. Please Help me out...
I am writing this code for console app.

```
int Per=25;
int inter=14527;
if(ifile)
{
    while(!ifile.eof())
    {
        ifile>>input;
                   /* doing some work here

                  */

        noOfWord++;

                 //i want to show this info to user..  Total percentage of words
                   read from file  ...like "Reading Words ... 25%"

        //if(noOfWord==inter)
        //{
        //  //Sleep(1000);
        //  cout<<"Reading Words..."<<Per<<"%";
        //  inter*=2;
        //  Per+=Per;
        //}
    }
}
else
{
    cout<<"File Not Open";
    exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`cout<<"Reading Words...<<Per<<"%";` is no good - you forgot to terminate the quote.

You want `cout<<"Reading Words..."<<Per<<"%"`;

Comment: I missed this one while Posting Code..  ..but not in my actual Code